# Mean row by imbricated levels of factors

Tags: r, row, mean, multi-level

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"),
                sub=rep(c(1:4),4),
                acc1=runif(16,0,3),
                acc2=runif(16,0,3),
                acc3=runif(16,0,3),
                acc4=runif(16,0,3))
```

What I want is to obtain the mean rows for each ID, which is to say I want to obtain the mean acc1, acc2, acc3 and acc4 for each level A, B, C and D by averaging the values for each sub (4 levels for each id), which would give something like this in the end (with the NAs replaced by the means I want of course):

```
dfavg = data.frame(id=c("A","B","C","D"),meanacc1=NA,meanacc2=NA,meanacc3=NA,meanacc4=NA)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

You can use any of the specialized packages `dplyr` or `data.table` or using `base R`.  Because you have a lot of columns that starts with `acc` to get the mean of, I choose `dplyr`.  Here, the idea is to first `group` the variable by `id` and then use `summarise_each` to get the `mean` of each column by `id` that starts_with `acc`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 <- df %>% 
           group_by(id) %>% 
           summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), starts_with("acc")) %>%
           rename(meanacc1=acc1, meanacc2=acc2, meanacc3=acc3, meanacc4=acc4) #this works but it requires more typing.
```

I would `rename` using `paste`

```
# colnames(df1)[-1] <- paste0("mean", colnames(df1)[-1])
```

gives the result

```
 #  id   meanacc1  meanacc2 meanacc3 meanacc4
 #1  A 1.7061929 2.401601 2.057538 1.643627
 #2  B 1.7172095 1.405389 2.132378 1.769410
 #3  C 1.4424233 1.737187 1.998414 1.137112
 #4  D 0.5468509 1.281781 1.790294 1.429353
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 nm1 <- paste0("acc", 1:4) #names of columns to do the `means`
 dt1 <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=id, .SDcols=nm1]
```

Here`.SD` implies `Subset of Data.table`, `.SDcols` are the columns to which we apply the `mean` operation.

```
 setnames(dt1, 2:5, paste0("mean", nm1)) #change the names of the concerned columns in the result
 dt1
```

Comment: +1, I just saw the post now and the code I had in my mind. Too late. How would you write the `rename()` part?

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks, Yesterday, when I tried the `rename` it was not working for some odd reason.  Perhaps I did something wrong.  I updated the post with using `rename`, though it requires more typing when you are renaming multiple variables.  I prefer to have some something along the lines of `rename(paste0("mean", starts_with("acc")= starts_with("acc"))` though it doesn't work

Comment: @jazzuro Thanks, it worked perfectly! Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 2):

(This must have been asked at least 20 times.) The `aggregate function applies the same function (given as the third argument) to all the columns of its first argument within groups defined by its second argument:

```
aggregate(df[-(1:2)], df[1],mean)
```

If you want to append the letters "mean" to the column names:

```
names(df2) <- paste0("mean", names(df2)
```

If you had wanted to do the column selection automatically then grep or grepl would work:

```
aggregate(df[ grepl("acc", names(df) )], df[1], mean)
```

Comment: Of course, there is also the `formula` method for `aggregate`: `aggregate(. ~ id, df[-2], mean)`.

Comment: Right. I keep forgetting about the formula methods since it makes it somewhat different than the other base summarization functions (`tapply`, `by`, `ave`) that have three arguments: data, index, function in that order. Easier to keep straight for me even if apparently less 'elegant'. For some reason I don't forget about the `xtabs.formula` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of other base R options:

`split` + `vapply` (since we know `vapply` would simplify to a matrix whenever possible)

```
t(vapply(split(df[-c(1, 2)], df[, 1]), colMeans, numeric(4L)))
```

`by` (with a `do.call(rbind, ...)` to get the final structure)

```
do.call(rbind, by(data = df[-c(1, 2)], INDICES = df[[1]], FUN = colMeans))
```

Both will give you something like this as your result:

```
#       acc1     acc2     acc3     acc4
# A 1.337496 2.091926 1.978835 1.799669
# B 1.287303 1.447884 1.297933 1.312325
# C 1.870008 1.145385 1.768011 1.252027
# D 1.682446 1.413716 1.582506 1.274925
```

---

The sample data used here was (with `set.seed`, for reproducibility):

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(id = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 4),
                sub = rep(c(1:4), 4),
                acc1 = runif(16, 0, 3),
                acc2 = runif(16, 0, 3),
                acc3 = runif(16, 0, 3),
                acc4 = runif(16, 0, 3))
```

Scaling up to 1M rows, these both perform quite well (though obviously not as fast as "dplyr" or "data.table").

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in base package itself using this:

```
 a <- list();

 for (i in 1:nlevels(df$id))
 {      
    a[[i]] = colMeans(subset(df, id==levels(df$id)[i])[,c(3,4,5,6)]) ##select columns of df of which you want to compute the means. In your example, 3, 4, 5 and 6 are the columns
 }
 meanDF <- cbind(data.frame(levels(df$id)), data.frame(matrix(unlist(a), nrow=4, ncol=4,  byrow=T)))

colnames(meanDF) = c("id", "meanacc1", "meanacc2", "meanacc3", "meanacc4")
meanDF

id meanacc1 meanacc2  meanacc3  meanacc4
A 1.464635 1.645898 1.7461862 1.026917
B 1.807555 1.097313 1.7135346 1.517892
C 1.350708 1.922609 0.8068907 1.607274
D 1.458911 0.726527 2.4643733 2.141865
```